# Rendering problem with double nested forms in Rails 6 + cocoon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using Rails 6 + [cocoon gem with vanilla js](https://github.com/oddcamp/cocoon-vanilla-js). I'm creating a website with quizzes, and quizzes, questions to them and answers to questions should be created on one page. Because of that i used double nested forms:

```
class Test < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :author, class_name: 'Teacher'
  belongs_to :article, optional: true

  has_many :questions, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions, reject_if: :all_blank
end
```

```
class Question < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :test

  has_many :answers, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, reject_if: :all_blank

  validates :title, presence: true
end
```

```
class Answer < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :question

  validates :content, presence: true
  validate :validate_max_answer_amount, on: :create

  scope :correct, -> { where(correct: true) }

  private

  def validate_max_answer_amount
    errors.add :base, :invalid_amount, message: 'Too many answers!' if question.answers.count >= 5
  end
end
```

The problem lies **precisely** in the display of fields when they are added using cocoon. For example:

***Can't post here images, because i have 1 rep, so [check here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/saLDn.jpg) please***

- Initial form - 1st screenshot
- Form after adding answers - 2nd screenshot (expected that new fields would be lower than old one)
- Form after adding questions - 3rd screenshot (expected that new fields would be lower than old one & that new fields would contain field for the first answer)

**My View files:**

`tests/_form.html.slim:`

```
=render 'shared/errors', object: @test

=form_with model: [:teacher, @test], local: true do |f|
  =f.number_field :author_id, class: 'hidden'
  =f.number_field :article_id, class: 'hidden'

  .mb-3.add-questions
    p
      | Add questions:
    .mb-3
      =f.fields_for :questions do |q|
        =render 'teacher/questions/question_fields', f: q
      br
      br
      =link_to_add_association 'Add one more question', f, :questions, partial: 'teacher/questions/question_fields'

  =f.submit 'Submit', class: 'btn btn-outline-success btn-lg mb-4'
```

`questions/_question_fields.html.slim:`

```
.mb-3.row
  .col-sm-2.col-form-label
    =f.label :title, 'Title'
  .col-sm-10.col-form-label
    =f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control'

=f.fields_for :answers do |a|
  =render 'teacher/answers/answer_fields', f: a

=link_to_add_association 'Add one more answer', f, :answers, partial: 'teacher/answers/answer_fields'
```

`answers/_answer_fields.html.slim:`

```
.mb-1.row
  .col-sm-1
  .col-sm-2.col-form-label
    =f.label :content, 'Enter content'
  .col-sm-8.col-form-label
    =f.text_field :content, class: 'form-control'
  .col-sm-1.col-form-label
    =f.check_box :correct, {class: 'form-check-input'}, true, false
```

I tried to remove `=render 'teacher/answers/answer_fields'` in `questions/_question_fields.html.slim`, but it didn't help with the problem with the questions. That is, new questions appeared anyway without an answer field.
I haven't figured out how to try to solve the problem with adding fields for answers (so that new fields appear below the old ones), so I hope for your help!

Comment: Images really don't help. Code speaks a thousand times more.

Comment: Do you see the `fields_for` generated elements in the rendered HTML source? Do you see the partial being rendered in `log/development.log`?

Comment: @tadman if i understood your comment right, then i should see something in my `development.log` file after clicking on "Add one more question" button. After clicking on this button, not a single line appears in this file. Also, the elements generated using `form_for :answers` are not present in the HTML for new questions. If it will help, I can add HTML code of this page.

Comment: Are you sure the JavaScript elements for Cocoon have been loaded correctly? Do you get any JavaScript errors?

Comment: @tadman as i said, i use vanilla js for cocoon. I did `yarn add @oddcamp/cocoon-vanilla-js`  and then added in my application.js this line `import "@oddcamp/cocoon-vanilla-js";`. There are no errors in console and in logs. Also i checked how does cocoon works with jQuery and i get same result. New fields are still rendered above the initial one. Maybe I did something wrong in both of this projects, but then I'm completely confused about it.

Comment: It's worth checking that the `import` actually got loaded correctly, either via a `console.log()` or a debugger breakpoint. I've seen cases where none of the Rails UJS stuff loads at all, and everything is mysteriously acting super weird.